# Copy to clipboard with Zeroclipboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zeroclipboard

I'm having a problem with the Zeroclipboard system, I think I've made a mistake with the code.
The peace that I would like to copy, won't copy.

My code that I'm using.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.zclip.min.js"></script>
             <script>
             $(document).ready(function()
             {

                $('a#copy-url').zclip(
              {
                 path:'js/ZeroClipboard.swf',
                   copy:$('input#shorturl').text()
              });

             });
             </script>
             <a href="#" id="copy-url" />Klik hier om de URL automatisch te kopi&euml;ren</a>
                    <div id="shorten_link">
                    <input type="text" name="url" id="shorturl" value="<?php echo $nwUrl; ?>" />
                    </div>
```

The input field is there, and the link to copy is also there, the only problem is that it won't copy. http://prntscr.com/2de6bg( for a screenshot of it.)

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you are including `zclip` __twice__ and jQuery __0 times__. Fix your includes.

Comment: I've added the line <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. But if I copy it, it will say : "Copy to the clipboard" but it won't copy it.

Comment: I can see `ZeroClipboard.swf` out there. Have you verified that your browser is not blocking Flash for current page?

Comment: You still need to remove one of the instances of `zclip` as you are currently including 2. Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: I've removed one for one to see which is the problem, no good result. The debug console gives me no errors back...